# HttpHeaders not being set in the HTTPResponse

Tags: java, post, http-headers, httpclient

I am trying to implement the following the curl command in Java using teh DefaultHttpClient

```
curl  -H "Content-Type:application/json"  -H "Authorization:Bearer rAnDoMSrings-" -X POST -d  @example.json http://api.rest.company.com/
```

Here is the client in Java

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = null;
    HttpResponse response = null;

    try {
        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(apiUrl);
        post.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        post.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " +authToken);
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        json.put("image_url", ");
        // Required field.
        json.put("job_fqn",");
        JSONArray routesJsonArray = new JSONArray();
        routesJsonArray.put(0, "");
        json.put("routes",routesJsonArray);
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString());
        post.setEntity(params);

        response = httpclient.execute(post);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception" + e);
    }
    finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

}
```

This gives a 401 Unauthorized error. Upon some debugging I found that none of the headers are being recognized and I get the follwoing

```
DEBUG [2016-06-30 14:24:16,559] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: Response contains no authentication challenges
```

Note that the curl command works fine. What have I missed?

Note that the outgoing headers are set right and I can log them out of the request object

Here is teh stack trace

```
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,665] org.apache.http.wire: >> "POST /v1/api HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,665] org.apache.http.wire: >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.wire: >> "Authorization: Bearer correct_token; Path=/; Domain=auth.server; Expires=Fri, 01 Jul 2016 17:51:08 UTC[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.wire: >> "Content-Length: 320[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.wire: >> "Host: api.rest.company.com[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.wire: >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.wire: >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.wire: >> "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.headers: >> POST /v1/jobs/docker HTTP/1.1
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.headers: >> Content-Type: application/json
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.headers: >> Authorization: Bearer correcttoken; Path=/; Domain=auth.server.com; Expires=Fri, 01 Jul 2016 17:51:08 UTC
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.headers: >> Content-Length: 320
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.headers: >> Host: api.rest.company.com
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.headers: >> Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.headers: >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.6 (java 1.5)
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,666] org.apache.http.wire: >> "{"correct Json Entity"}"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,667] org.apache.http.wire: << "HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,667] org.apache.http.wire: << "Server: nginx[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.wire: << "Date: Thu, 30 Jun 2016 17:51:08 GMT[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.wire: << "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.wire: << "Content-Length: 62[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.wire: << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.wire: << "Minimum-Apc-Version: 2.0.0[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.wire: << "[\r][\n]"
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection: Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.headers: << HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.headers: << Server: nginx
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.headers: << Date: Thu, 30 Jun 2016 17:51:08 GMT
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.headers: << Content-Type: application/json
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.headers: << Content-Length: 62
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.headers: << Connection: keep-alive
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.headers: << Minimum-Apc-Version: 2.0.0
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: Authentication required
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: api.rest.company:80 requested authentication
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,668] org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient: Response contains no authentication challenges
```

Can it be related to the following two lines in the log

```
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,665] org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache: Auth cache not set in the context
DEBUG [2016-06-30 17:51:08,665] org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication: Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
```

Could it be that the header is lost after being redirected by the nginx proxy?

Comment: If the wire log contains teh authentication Bearer token doesnt it mean that its is transfered to the api endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the reason is you have used post.addHeader. Instead you should use post.setHeader. The code should be like the following from my point of view

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("image_url", "http://xx.xx");  // set the image_url parameter's value here
json.put("job_fqn", "xx");              // set the job_fqn parameter's value here
JSONArray routesJsonArray = new JSONArray();
routesJsonArray.put(0, "");
json.put("routes",routesJsonArray);

try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(API_URL);


        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json.toString(), "UTF-8");
        httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + authToken);
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
        httpPost.setEntity(params);

        final HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 30000);
        httpPost.setParams(httpParams);

        LOGGER.debug("Request is being processed. HTTP Post: [" + EntityUtils.toString(httpPost.getEntity()) + "]");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        String responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());

        LOGGER.debug("Response String: " + responseStr);


        if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
            LOGGER.info("Request is successful!");
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Request failed!");
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe){
        LOGGER.error("ClientProtocolException while processing the request", cpe);
        return -1;
    }catch (SocketTimeoutException ste){
        LOGGER.error("SocketTimeoutException while processing the request", ste);
        return -1;
    }catch (IOException e){
        LOGGER.error("IOException while processing the request", e);
        return -1;
    }catch (Exception e){
        LOGGER.error("Exception while processing the request", e);
        return -1;
    }
```